# ¿Por que mi query no hace distincion entre 2 caracteres?

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure-sql

Buen dia.
El dia de hoy vengo solicitando su ayuda para el siguiente caso:
Ando trabajando en un proyecto donde tengo que hacer consultas entre diferentes servidores, por lo cual me he apoyado con la funcion "OpenQuery".
Lo que hago es que mediante esta funcion solicito que se llene una tabla previamente creda con los siguientes datos solicitados:

```
CREATE TABLE #Secuencia
 (ID INT IDENTITY NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
 [Desde] VARCHAR(7), 
 [Hasta] VARCHAR(7),
 [Modelo] VARCHAR(7),
 [Plataforma] VARCHAR(10),
 [Status] VARCHAR(10),
 [Palletize] NVARCHAR(2),
 [PlatCase] VARCHAR(10),

 
 ) --SE CREA LA TABLA DE SECUENCIA 


INSERT INTO #Secuencia
SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY([10.8.7], 'SELECT TOP(300) ACTUAL_FROM,ACTUAL_TO,  REPLACE(UNIT_NO,''31020'','''') as UNIT_NO, ''VACIO'', ''NA'',PROGRESS17,''NA'' FROM [G5_MEX].[dbo].[T_ACT_DAT] WHERE ACTUAL_FROM not like ''__9%'' ')
```

Una de las columnas que recibe datos es la que se llama "Palletize" esta recibe uno de estos dos caracteres : '△' ó '○'.
Viendose de la siguiente manera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Busco su apoyo puesto que tengo un problema al trabajar con esta columna ya que mi query actual lo que busca hacer es que dependiendo del caracter que se encuentre en la columna va a dar un juicio dependiendo de si se trata de '△' ó '○' y al parecer mi query no logra hacer distincion entre estos caracteres, los toma como si fueran lo mismo, anexo el query que estoy usando para comparar:

```
DECLARE @Circulo nvarchar(1)


SET @Circulo = (SELECT Palletize FROM #Secuencia WHERE ID = 1)

IF @Circulo like '△'
begin
PRINT 'es triangulo'
end 
ELSE IF @Circulo like '○'
BEGIN
PRINT 'es circulo'
end
```

El query que mostre es muy simple y no es el query final que usare solo lo use para ver el motivo de que la distincion no se haga correctamente. Al correr el query lo que este hace es que no entra en ninguna condicion y unicamente me aparece que los comandos fueron completados. Llevo varios intentos buscando una solucion pero hasta el momento no he encontrado nada.

Nota: Lo que intento realizar ya lo he hecho con anterioridad corriendo mi consulta en el servidor donde se encuentra la tabla y si distingue entre los 2 sin problema, al parecer solo ocurre esto al correrlo en este otro servidor.

Nota 2: Uso el comparador like pero de igual manera ya he usado el comparador "=" y obtengo el mismo resultado.

Comment: esos son caracteres ascii de algun tipo, que al traerlos, los esta codificando de otra forma... casi seguro que tu problema esta ahi.... fijate que codificacion tienen en el nuevo servidor...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

El problema es que el literal '△' o '○' no lo estás definiendo como un cadena unicode:

```
SELECT  ASCII('△') Triangulo,
        ASCII('○')  Circulo
```

| Triangulo | Circulo |
| --- | --- |
| 63 | 63 |

Como primer solución, limita los caracteres al conjunto ascii estándar, pero como seguramente esa no es una solución, indica que los literales son multibyte:

```
SET @Circulo = N'○'

IF @Circulo like N'△'
begin
PRINT 'es triangulo'
end 
ELSE IF @Circulo like N'○'
BEGIN
PRINT 'es circulo'
end
```

Por cierto, en servidores distintos, no está de más, como te mencionó gbianchi, verificar también la `collation` de la base y la que se usa en la columna `Palletize` y chequear que sea la misma en ambos servidores, ya que seguramente de ahí se derive este problema.

Comment: Cabe señalar, que el código ASCII 63 es un signo de interrogación.

Comment: Que tal Patricio agradezco tu respuesta, probe la solucion que me comentaste y efectivamente me funcionó y claro revisare la collation de la db para poder cersiorarme de que las dos columnas sean la misma en ambos servidores, una vez mas muchas gracias y saludos!